# Using Existing sqlite Database with android ADT

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am developing an app in android which consists of activities that need to connect to the Database. I am having an existing sqlite DB with me. But I don't know how to include it in my project. This might be a  very basic question, but as I am a newbie, I am finding it quite complex to get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use an existing database with an Android application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9109438/how-to-use-an-existing-database-with-an-android-application)

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution, by far, is to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper). You add one JAR to your project, package your database in a ZIP file in a specified location in your project's `assets/` directory, then use `SQLiteAssetHelper` to access your database (much like you would use `SQLiteOpenHelper`).

Answer (score 0):

try to read more about making a DatabaseHelper extension class

this really helped me during my first database driven app

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/119293/Using-SQLite-Database-with-Android

Answer (score 0):

The name of this feature of transfer database in android called database Ship.
`I have already complete database ship`[Using your own SQLite database in Android applications](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Also you can see this [Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513084/how-to-ship-an-android-application-with-a-database)